# When using Skype all other audio is muted

Tags: skype

As the title says, whenever I use Skype all other audio on my computer is muted. As well as that, if sound is playing from anything else and I try and make a Skype call, it won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Install `pavucontrol` package. After you installed that package, `Skype options -> Sound devices` dialog presents a button to open that volume control dialog.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I installed the package but you lost me at "dialog presents a button to open that volume control dialog." I don't understand. .

Comment: Yeah I definitely do not have that. I can open PulseAudio Volume Control manually but how do I unmute everything? It doesn't show anything as muted.

Comment: Did You install `pavucontrol`?

Comment: Yes I did, I can open it manually but there is no option within Skype. I also do not have any option for PulseAudio in microphone/speakers/ringing

Comment: Check out [my source](http://tronprog.blogspot.ru/2011/05/making-microphone-work-in-kubuntu-natty.html)

Comment: I see, but it doesn't mention my problem.

Comment: Oh, I misread Your question. I thought You cound not get audio wokring in skype. Still -- what does `pavucontrol` shows You when You use skype? There might be something to toggle.

Comment: Opening the PulseAudio Volume Control seems to break Skype, I can't get it to make any sound or make a call.

Comment: Scratch that, I managed to get Skype working again by messing around with the configuration menus. My original problem still stands, though.

Comment: I would try re-installing the skype and also installing the proprientary version from the official web-site if I were You.

Comment: I've already tried re-installing, but I did it again with no luck. This is getting very annoying.

Comment: Another thing to note, Skype does not show inside of PulseAudio Volume Control while in use. If I opened a YouTube video while in a Skype call, the video would list and the bar would be moving, but no audio.